# CSS - Multiple background images from different rules

Tags: css, background-image

I know that I can add multiple superimposed background images to one element by declaring them in one statement, like this:

```
.background1.background2{
    background-image: url(background1.png), url(background2.png);
    background-position: center, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    backgroun-size: 100%, 50%
}
```

However, if I try to do so through multiple rules, as such:

```
.background1{
    background-image: url(background1.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.background2{
    background-image: url(background2.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}
```

Then the second rule overwrites the first one. Is there a way to add multiple background-images to an element through different rules without one overwriting the other?

I could achieve the same effect through absolutely positioned divs, but if it's possible, I think it'd be more elegant to do it via css.

Answer (score 1):

Your css rules conflict and, in that case, it falls to position in the file, with the latter rule taking precedence.  To get around this, you need to raise the specificity of the selector and write the rule with the combined background-url property.

That's exactly what you have in the first snippet, so that's "correct".  If you want to do it in multiple selectors, that's impossible

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case there are several potential background images to add to these elements, so writing selector for every possible combination would make for one very, very long css file. Seems like I'll have to settle for using some absolutely positioned divs.